# iOS code for downloading a file using HTTP only if it was changed

Tags: ios, http

I am looking for a **complete piece of code** for iOS for downloading a file in background using HTTP but only if the file was updated on the server.

Mainly in order to do that you have to send a request and set `if-modified-since` for it.

Shortly, I want to obtain the same functionality as `wget --timestamp <url>`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `if-modified-since` header field (or any other header field) in a NSMutableURLRequest object.